# How to have get and post endpoint from same flask-restplus Resource class?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restplus

I have the below class that inherits from flask-restplus.Resource.

```
class Patient(Resource):
    """ Patient endpoint."""
    @clinic_api_ns.route("/patient/add/")
    def post(self):
        # TODO: add a patient.
        return {}

    @clinc_api_ns.route("/patient/<string:name>")
    def get(self, name):
        # TODO: get a patient record
        return {}
```

I want to achieve 2 endpoints from the above but it doesnt work 
it throws error:

> /site-packages/flask_restplus/api.py", line 287, in _register_view
>       resource_func = self.output(resource.as_view(endpoint, self, *resource_class_args, AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the decorators at the class instead of the functions.

Your API will hit the same endpoint "/patient" and the method will determine which function is called.  Get, post, put, and delete.

If you need different API endpoint you will need 2 Resource classes, one for each path.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, [`.route()` decorators](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#flask_restplus.Namespace.route) are meant to be used on `Resource` classes only - not their methods. You have to define two separate resources - similar to how `Todo` and `TodoList` are defined [in the full example in the docs](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/example.html).